# MediaPlayer воспроизведение

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

На сайте нашёл код:

```
public void onClick (View v){
       index = 0;
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[index] );
       mp.setLooping(false);
       mp.start();
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
               if(index < sounds.length-1){
                   index++;
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[index]);
                   mp.start();
                   mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
               }
               else mp.release();
           }
       });
}
```

Но он воспроизводит все треки друг за другом. Может кто-нибудь подскажет: как сделать при нажатии на кнопку воспроизведение одного трека? И пока трек воспроизводится, кнопка должна быть неактивна, а следующее нажатие воспроизводит второй трек.
И ещё как сделать управление с кнопки громкости+ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так пропишите такое поведение.
При нажатии делаете кнопку неактивной, а по окончании возвращаете:

```
int index = 0; //дабы не сбрасывалось по нажатию на кнопку выносим 
public void onClick (View v){
       yourButton.setEnabled(false); //кнопка неактивна
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[index]);
       mp.setLooping(false);
       mp.start();
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
               yourButton.setEnabled(true); //после окончания воспроизведения делаем кнопку активной
               mp.release();
               if(index < sounds.length-1){
                   index++; //увеличиваем счетчик для воспроизведения следующего трека
               } else {
                   index = 0; //сбрасываем в 0
               }
           }
       });
}
```

Comment: Да, ты прав, твой ответ правильный

Comment: Спасибо работает!!!

Comment: @Василий если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его галочкой как правильный для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на этот топик.

Answer (score 0):

Переписать код метода `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)`:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
    mp.release();
    v.setEnabled(true);
    if(index < sounds.length-1) {
        index++;
    }
}
```

Чтобы следующий трек проиграть, вам надо индекс увеличить на один